# Excel 2007 - Find the top 10 in a SUBTOTAL with a formula, not with AGGREGATE

Tags: arrays, excel, formula

I am using Excel 2007, I have seen that the `AGGREGATE` function will do what I want it to do, alas, it doesn't exist in 2007.

I had the following formula for getting the top 10 products in a dataset.

```
=INDEX($A$5:$W$24389,MATCH(LARGE($V$5:$V$24389,BO1),$V$5:$V$24389,0),1)
```

BO1:BX1 is a list from 1 to 10 (to give that `k` number of result).

This works beautifully, until the list is then put into subtotals. It then returns `""` (well, `0`) as it find the `MAX` value as one of the subtotals.

How do I get the top 10, that ignores the `SUBTOTAL`s?

Here was my thinking....
[From MrExcel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/508325-how-ignore-blank-rows-array.html)
<-- This nicely omits cells that are blank, but returns them one by one into a list. I think I need to return this array in the formula, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: You would have a problem with that INDEX formula if there are duplicate values in the top 10 ( because it will return the same product for each of the duplicates). I assume duplicates might be possible?

Comment: Yes, I do not mind duplicates for this example to be honest. It's the blank cells that are really tripping me up, and I'm still sure the key is to get an array where the blanks are removed. Or something along the lines of RANGEIF(cell<>"",RANGE).

Comment: Which column is it which contains these blanks which can be used as a means to exclude those rows from the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column A values (the products) are always blank on the "subtotal" rows it should be sufficient to use this version if you don't have **any** duplicates in column V:

`=INDEX($A$5:$A$24389,MATCH(LARGE(IF($A$5:$A$24389<>"",$V$5:$V$24389),BO1),$V$5:$V$24389,0))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

....but assuming there might be duplicate values in column V (either between the values themselves or between values and subtotals) use this formula in the first cell(`BO2`?)

`=INDEX($A$5:$A$24389,MATCH(LARGE(IF($A$5:$A$24389<>"",$V$5:$V$24389),BO1),IF($A$5:$A$24389<>"",$V$5:$V$24389),0))`

......and then in `BP2` use this version:

`=INDEX($A$5:$A$24389,MATCH(LARGE(IF($A$5:$A$24389<>"",$V$5:$V$24389),BP1),IF(ISNA(MATCH($A$5:$A$24389,$BO2:BO2,0)),IF($A$5:$A$24389<>"",$V$5:$V$24389)),0))`

also confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied across

Comment: The IF clause needs to be repeated in MATCH's lookup_array as well. Otherwise, what's to say that the maximum value which corresponds to a non-blank column A entry doesn't also occur for a row which corresponds to a blank column A entry, and one having a lesser row number to boot?

Comment: @XOR LX, I was assuming that the subtotals would all be greater than the individual values but I take your point - there's no reason why that should be the case, I'll amend accordingly - thanks

Comment: Well done guys. Indeed, the subtotals can often be smaller than some of (the products) and therefore, the solution above is the correct one. Many thanks for this, and I have deepened my understanding of these arrays within Excel. Great work!

Answer (score 0):

If you have filtered data, here is a way to list all the visible values in sorted order:

Say we start with:

[image]

We add a "helper" column in **C** so in **C2** enter:

```
=IF(SUBTOTAL(3,A2:A2)=0,MIN($C$1:C1)-1,SUBTOTAL(3,$A$2:$A2))
```

and copy down.  We now filter to see only the "blues".

[image]

No matter how we filter, column **C** will be a simple sequential list marking the visible items.

In **D21** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$20,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),$C$2:$C$20,0)),"")
```

Column **D** represents the visible items in column **B** items in their order of appearance.  In **E21** enter:

```
=IFERROR(RANK(D21,$D$21:$D$99,0)+COUNTIF(D$21:D21,D21)-1,"")
```

and copy down.  Column **E** applies a unique rank to each item in column **D**.  Finally in **G21** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$21:$D$99,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),$E$21:$E$99,0)),"")
```

and copy down.  Column **G** represents the items in column **D** in top-down sorted order.

[image]

Comment: Whilst this is good methodology, it's not the solution to my problem. Thank you for your time.